# Can't type in search box on Wordpress mobile nav menu

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to hack a search box into a wordpress mobile nav menu and I have no idea why I can't type into it. I'm guessing the issue is related to the cursor but can't find more info on how to fix it and I seem to have reached the limits of my abilities! 
Thanks for your guidance :)
Edit (forgot the link): https://www.winebounty.com (mobile version)
[image: wordpress mobile nav issue]

Comment: Unfortunately a screenshot doesn't do anybody much good. We'll need a link and/or the HTML/CSS/JS markup in order to do anything. Odds are you've got a `z-index` or `position` issue and and element is covered by an element that's covering it.

Comment: Woops sorry, I just added the link. Tried adding/editing z-index and position but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link, my assumption was incorrect. You are able to type into it, and it's not being blocked by another element. The issue is with the font size, it's set to `0px`. I found this out by opening up Chrome Dev Tools, and clicking on **Computed** that shows *all* styles that are applied to that element.

In your style.css you have the following on line 48999:

```
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit; /* <-- Culprit */
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

It's inheriting the font-size from line 13922:

```
#mega_main_menu, #mega_main_menu>.menu_holder, 
#mega_main_menu>.menu_holder>.menu_inner, 
#mega_main_menu>.menu_holder>.menu_inner>.mega_main_menu_ul {
    font-size: 0; /* <-- This guy */
    letter-spacing: 0;
    word-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

You just need to add an appropriate font-size to that search input, and it will work, as seen here:

[image: Preview of Dev Tools]

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for giving me your thought process for finding the culprit. Much appreciated!